# JQuery: animate child div together with parent div

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I'm new to JQuery animation, this seems like a relatively simple question but I've done some digging and can't find any solutions elsewhere.

I have a parent div that I want to set to a certain percentage height, e.g.

```
$('#parent').animate({
    height: "75%"
});
```

There is a child div that I want to be 100% of the height of the parent.

What is the best way for me to animate the two together simultaneously, so that whatever height I decide to animate the parent to, 50%, 30%, 22.937%, the child remains at 100% of the parent height but grows/shrinks alongside the parent?

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/azw2F/2/

I guess I could scrap the percentages, figure out what the heights would be in pixels from the container height, and then animate the parent and child to the same pixel value, but is there an easier way?

Thank you,
Adam

**EDIT**

The issue seems to be related to whether the child div is positioned within the dimensions of the parent. Any parts of the child div that are outside of the dimensions are not animated, they just 'pop in' at the end once the animation is finished.

Child within parent: http://jsfiddle.net/azw2F/9
Child partially outside parent: http://jsfiddle.net/azw2F/10

I guess the HTML should probably be restructured so the parent is a sibling instead, and that might be the only answer (other than what I said about calculating the pixels). I guess I was just hoping that there was some JQuery animate magic I was unaware of.

Comment: why position:absolute; for #child.check this one http://jsfiddle.net/azw2F/3/ is this your desire result.

Comment: I do still need position:absolute on the child unfortunately, as I need to alter it's 'left' property. That is a perfect illustration of my desired result though, thank you :)

Comment: @mani you should put it as an answer so it can be accepted

Comment: `left` is still a valid property of non-absolutely positioned objects.  [According to the W3](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/left), left specifies `"...specifies how far positioned box's left margin edge is."`, effectively giving the behavior of an offset.  If you relatively position an object, left will offset it from its natural spot while (I believe) leaving its flow box in place.  Don't know if that helps, just sharing the knowledge!

Comment: Interesting. I think (from fiddling) that it works if the child is within the width of the parent: http://jsfiddle.net/azw2F/9/, but when parts of it are outside the width of the parent, those parts do not animate with it but just refreshes to the correct height at the end:http://jsfiddle.net/azw2F/10/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution was this: http://jsfiddle.net/azw2F/11/

Add `overflow:visible!important;` to the parent div when the child div is partially outside of it, i.e. the child div is overflowing out of the parent. Annoyingly simple when you think about it!

Answer (score 1):

```
I have two solution for your problem
```

first one `with position:absolute` on the child

http://jsfiddle.net/azw2F/4/

second one `without position:absolute` on the child which i have post earlier

http://jsfiddle.net/azw2F/3/

Comment: Hi, thanks but as I mentioned in my comment, I need to be able to set the 'left' property, as soon as you do that your fiddle no longer works.

Comment: I just tested mani's first example with a `left` of `10px` on the child.  Seemed to work fine, although it looks like he forgot to set a percent height on `#child`.

Comment: @ Adam Marshall sorry but i didn't get your point, what exactly you wana do with left property.if you still want to use left you can try left:100px;

Comment: See my comment on the main question. Specifically I need to correct myself "I need to be able to set the 'left' property so that the child div is positioned to the side of the parent div"